# Unable to connect to any port other than 22 (ssh) AWS

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an ubuntu instance on AWS and I run mongod on the server. The mongod has bind ip set to 0.0.0.0 and verified using netstat.

```
sudo netstat -nltp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1055/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1049/mongod
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1055/sshd
```

I have also set security group rules on AWS EC2 console such that inbound connections from my public ip on port 27017 are allowed. I am not able to connect from my laptop to the mongod (27017).

```
telnet ec2-<ip-removed>.compute-1.amazonaws.com 27017                    1 ↵
Trying <ip-removed>...
telnet: connect to address <ip-removed>: Operation timed out
```

However I have no problem connecting to ssh on port 22 from my laptop

```
telnet ec2-<ip-removed>.compute-1.amazonaws.com 22                    130 ↵
Trying <ip-removed>...
Connected to ec2-<ip-removed>.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
```

This setup was working fine a week ago and suddenly my laptop client refuses to connect to the mongo. I tried another service on port 6800 with inbound rules set and bind ip set to 0.0.0.0/32 it is also not able to connect. I have no other rules set, nor do I have iptables or firewall on the instance.

I have also tried rebooting the server, no luck there.

Also connecting to mongo from the server itself works

```
ubuntu@aws$ telnet localhost 27017
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
```

Comment: For the record you don't need to do `telnet ec2-<ip-removed>.compute-1.amazonaws.com` you can just do `telnet <ip-removed>`. Did your external ip address change or become disassociated from the instance?

Comment: Thank you for the tip :) . No my ip did not change, its static. Also I can connect via ssh on 22, but no other port will connect :(

Comment: *Has* to be a firewall issue... you can check if iptables is running by doing `iptables -L -vn`, if it lists out any rules, it's running. If it is running then you can stop it with `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`. And make doubly sure you don't have any AWS security policies in place.

Comment: Hmmm mongod is not bound to an IPv6 ip, but sshd is, I wonder if that's the issue.

Comment: Any luck getting access?

Comment: Hi mike I fell asleep. I think you may be onto something. Only sshd is bound to IPv6.  Thanks for the tip, I'll check as soon as I get to work.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes iptables were changed. My colleague changed rules when I was away and I didn't know about it. I disabled it (`$ service ufw stop`) and now I can connect, Thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, port access from an external network was blocked via iptables running on the instance.

My approach to iptables/AWS access policies is to always use an "open" AWS access policy and lock everything down using iptables. This way, controlling access is closer to the instance, and doesn't overly complicate things by layering access policies over one another.

And tbh, your mongod instance shouldn't even be in a DMZ (publicly accessible), you should setup iptables to only allow access to the mongod instance from internal networks. Chances are you have an "app server" which needs access to the mongod so make the app server publicly accessible, not the mongod instance.

Here is an example of iptables running on one of my "docstore" instances:

```
root@service-a-2.sn3.vpc3.example.com ~ # -> iptables -L -vn
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  1419   15M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 001 accept all to lo interface */
  27M  4531M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 005 accept related established rules */ state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth0   *       10.3.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0           /* 015 accept internal icmp */ state NEW
 74     4440 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       10.3.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 22 /* 777 accepts ssh */ state NEW
 420K    25M ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       10.3.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 27017 /* 777 allow mongo access */ state NEW
 462K    28M ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       10.3.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 3306 /* 777 allow mysql access */ state NEW
  656  28976 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 999 drop all INPUT */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 27M packets, 9639M bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Notice that I am using CIDR (classless inter-domain routing) blocks to identify internal networks, this way you don't get bogged down having to specify actual ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB only binds to localhost by default. You have update its configuration to enable outside access.

> New in version 2.6: mongod installed from official .deb and .rpm
>   packages have the bind_ip configuration set to 127.0.0.1 by default.

Source: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/#security-considerations

Here's a tutorial that shows how to do it: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/

Comment: `0.0.0.0:27017` indicates it's bound to all available ips, so if he indeed has an elastic ip bound to that instance, mongod should be bound to it as well.